# T-SQL Window Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

For the sake of example, I have the following data set:
**ToyReferenceNumber**, **Company**, **CompositeCalculatedField**, **PermanentRecallDate**, **ReturnToStoreDate**

Basically, there could be 3-4 entries for each item (imaginary company TheToyCompany, or TTC):

```
TTC-011-0934, TTC, calculation, NULL, 2017-03-01 12:01:01.00
TTC-011-0934, TTC, calculation, NULL, 2014-05-01 12:01:01.00
TTC-011-0934, TTC, calculation, NULL, 2011-08-27 12:01:01.00
TTC-994-0132, TTC, calculation, 2017-06-12 12:01:01.00, NULL
TTC-994-0132, TTC, calculation, NULL, 2017-02-01 12:01:01.00
TTC-354-0122, TTC, calculation, NULL, 2015-03-01 12:01:01.00
TTC-354-0122, TTC, calculation, NULL, NULL
```

From a business logic standpoint, for the first product (0934), it had a recall multiple times (which printing or prod batch, we don't care), but was fixed and returned to stores after each.

For 0132, it was attempted to fix the defect, but then the company simply decided to scrap the product as it was not selling anyway.

For 0122, a product batch was recalled, fixed, and then sent to stores on 2015-03-01, but a current batch is currently being fixed (hence, the NULL, NULL).

What management wants is a report that current fix-factory billing (e.g. time sheets for guys who fix the toys).

Pseudo-Query:

```
 For a given product, return only the record with NULL, NULL dates (actively being fixed)
    IF not null, null, return only the record with the PermanentRecallDate
    IF no PermanentRecallDate, return only the record with the latest ReturnToStoreDate
```

The oracle query was basically the same as the following pseudo-code:

```
SELECT <normal columns> 
,MAX(ts.PermanentRecallDate) KEEP (dense_rank last order by ts.PermanentRecallDate NULLS LAST) PERANENTRECALLDATE
,MAX(ts.ReturnToStoreDate) KEEP (dense_rank last order by ts.ReturnToStoreDate NULLS LAST) RETURNTOSTOREDATE
```

The oracle query is pretty straightforward, but I need it in T-SQL:

```
WITH CTE_ToyReferenceExport
AS
(
SELECT ts.ToyReferenceNumber AS TOYNUM
    ,tsh.Company AS COMPANY
    ,MAX(largeSetofCalculations) AS CompositeCalculatedField
    ,MAX(ts.PermanentRecallDate) AS PERMANETRECALL
    ,MAX(ts.ReturnToStoreDate) AS RETURNTOSTORE
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ts.ToyReferenceNumber ORDER BY ts.PermanentRecallDate) as PRDRank
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ts.ToyReferenceNumber ORDER BY ts.(ReturnToStoreDate) AS RTSDRank

    FROM origin.ToyStaging ts
    JOIN origin.ToyOrders to ON ts.ordernumer = to.ordno
    JOIN origin.ToyShipment tsh ON to.packno = tsh.crateno
    LEFT JOIN origin.Shippers sh ON to.packno = sh.cratenum AND 'calcField' = sh.originfield
GROUP BY ts.ToyReferenceNumber, tsh.Company, ts.permanentrecalldate, ts.returntostoredate
)
```

There is a lot more to it, but the main thing that trips me up is getting the result set returned by "MAX..Keep Dense_rank last order by.. NULLS LAST" logic.

Any help would be appreciated.  SQL Server 2012 is the version.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the maximum date if none are `NULL`, and `NULL` if at least one is.  If this is right:

```
SELECT <normal columns>,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) <> COUNT(ts.PermanentRecallDate) THEN NULL
             ELSE MAX(ts.PermanentRecallDate)
        END) as PERANENTRECALLDATE,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) <> COUNT(ts.ReturnToStoreDate) THEN NULL
             ELSE MAX(ts.ReturnToStoreDate)
        END) as RETURNTOSTOREDATE
```

Comment: Actually, given a the following partition: TTC-354-0122, TTC, calculation, NULL, 2015-03-01 12:01:01.00
TTC-354-0122, TTC, calculation, NULL, NULL
 I need the row (the whole row) that has NULL, NULL in it.  If there is no NULL, NULL row, I need the row with the latest permanent recall date, unless that is null for that toy, in which case I need the row with the latest ReturnToStoreDate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method of implementing your requirements.

```
WITH Limits AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ToyReferenceNumber
       , FIRST_VALUE(PermanentRecallDate) 
               OVER (PARTITION BY ToyReferenceNumber
                         ORDER BY CASE WHEN ReturnToStoreDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
                                , CASE WHEN PermanentRecallDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
                                , PermanentRecallDate DESC) PermanentRecallDate
       , FIRST_VALUE(ReturnToStoreDate)
               OVER (PARTITION BY ToyReferenceNumber
                         ORDER BY CASE WHEN ReturnToStoreDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
                                , ReturnToStoreDate DESC) ReturnToStoreDate
    FROM ToyStaging
)
SELECT ts.* 
  FROM ToyStaging TS
  JOIN Limits L
    ON TS.ToyReferenceNumber = L.ToyReferenceNumber
   AND (L.PermanentRecallDate IS NULL 
        and ts.PermanentRecallDate is null
        OR TS.PermanentRecallDate = L.PermanentRecallDate)
   AND (L.ReturnToStoreDate IS NULL
        AND ts.ReturnToStoreDate is null
        OR TS.ReturnToStoreDate = L.ReturnToStoreDate)
```

In the `Limits` CTE the `FIRST_VALUE` analytic functions will both return null if a null null record exists for a given `ToyReferenceNumber`. Otherwise the `PermanentRecallDate` column will return the latest `PermanentRecallDate`, and the `ReturnToStoreDate` column will return the latest `ReturnToStoreDate` when no `PermanentRecallDate` exist thereby instantiating your rules as to which record to return.  The distinct prunes out the duplicate records, and then `Limits` is joined back to `ToyStaging` to get the desired data.

Given your sample data the Limits CTE returns:

```
| ToyReferenceNumber |    PermanentRecallDate |      ReturnToStoreDate |
|--------------------|------------------------|------------------------|
|       TTC-011-0934 |                 (null) | 2017-03-01 12:01:01.00 |
|       TTC-354-0122 |                 (null) |                 (null) |
|       TTC-994-0132 | 2017-06-12 12:01:01.00 |                 (null) |
```

and the whole query returns:

```
| ToyReferenceNumber | Company | CompositeCalculatedField |    PermanentRecallDate |      ReturnToStoreDate |
|--------------------|---------|--------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|
|       TTC-011-0934 |     TTC |              calculation |                 (null) | 2017-03-01 12:01:01.00 |
|       TTC-354-0122 |     TTC |              calculation |                 (null) |                 (null) |
|       TTC-994-0132 |     TTC |              calculation | 2017-06-12 12:01:01.00 |                 (null) |
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53807/37) to see it in action.